# sourcetree hook with python

Tags: python, git, atlassian-sourcetree, gitpython

I have a git hook, "commit-msg"

and it looks something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
python .git/hooks/Foo.py
```

Inside my Foo.py

I have:

```
import git
# doing some stuff based on git (evaluating latest changes)
```

when I commit using sourcetree if fails to run the hook ( also it does not commit )

```
//...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File ".git/hooks/Foo.py", line 2, in <module>
        import git
    ImportError: No module named git
//...
```

but if I commit directly from the terminal the hook works as expected.

Any suggestions to fix the commit on source tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this to your git hook file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

[See this SourceTree issue](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/SourceTree-Hook-failing-because-paths-don-t-seem-to-be-set/qaq-p/274792)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that the app called SourceTree is not launched through an evironment that has the missing module. It has a great chance that you have a python virtual environment activated when you are using the terminal.

1. close SourceTree
2. open the terminal
3. in the terminal activate the virtual environment you use when you are developing the project (if you don't have a clue what I am talking about, just skip this step and hope it will work anyway)
4. in the terminal start SourceTree

Now SourceTree is running under an environment that has the missing module, so everything will be fine.